# Why is the Binding ItemSource property not found on my ViewModel?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, data-binding

I have Xamarin Forms app to show a deck of cards. The `Deck` is initialized with a static collection in the `App` class. (A breakpoint shows it is populated). The `MainPage` has a `MainPageViewModel` set as the BindingContext:

```
Public MainPage(){
    InitilizeComponent();
    BindingContext = new MainPageViewModel()
}
```

The `MainPageViewModel` has a simple property to retrieve the populated `Deck.Cards`:

`public static IEnumerable<Card> Cards { get { return Deck.Cards; }}`

This is used in a Carousel collection in the main page.

However, the view is empty! I see

**`[0: ] Binding: 'Cards' property not found on 'mypackage.ViewModels.MainPageViewModel', target property 'Xamarin.Forms.CarouselView.ItemsSource'**

Why is the property not found? It is public and IEnumerable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that your Xaml currently has `ItemsSource={Binding Cards}`, then make Cards non-static and it'll work.

If you want to keep Cards a static property, use x:Static:

`ItemsSource={x:Static vm:MainPageViewModel.Cards}`

And make sure you declare the namespace: `xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:mypackage.ViewModels"` at the top of your Xaml file.

Answer (score 1):

Change this:

```
public static IEnumerable<Card> Cards { get { return Deck.Cards; }}
```

to this:

```
public ObservableCollection<Card> Cards{ get {return new ObservableCollection<Card>(Deck.Cards.ToList()); }}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Ah! There was a fatal typo in the original question. The property *is* defined on the MainPageViewModel. Sorry!

Comment: It was the x:Static attribute in the definition that fixed it (see accepted answer) but voted this up - the collection should be observable if changes need to be notified.